# i think my multiresolution have problem but i dont know what

Tags: multiresolution

This is my object without multiresolution and without baked normal map
[image]

and this is with multiresolution
[image]

and this is with baked normal map of multiresolution
[image]

dont know why its not simmilar at all.
The baked normal map looks it goes in, unlike multiresolution... do i me shome checks? or multiresolution is just like this?
i just followed youtube, how to bake normal  map for baking multiresoultion..

Comment: when you baked, in the Multires modifier, did you come back to the level of resolution you want for your object (which may be 0)?

Comment: Maybe the problem is with the normal map... is it set to non-colour (on the image texture node)? It sometimes causes this problem.

Comment: hmm... yop i level it to 0 and aslo set it to non colour... T,T i even tried level it to 1 and bake. its still the same.. anyway thanks for the reply!

Comment: Have you checked the "Bake from Multires" option in the bake settings? What does the baked normal map look like? Had you plugged in (another) normal map when you baked it?